# Is it possible to allow anonymous access to some pages in windows authentication?

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, windows-authentication

I am trying to implement windows authentication in Asp.net core 2.0.
here i have done windows authentication which very easy by only selecting **windows authentication** option while creating the solution,
but here i want to make some pages **publicly available** and for this i tried something like below code which is not working.

```
[Authorize(Roles = "Administrator")]
public IActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }

 [AllowAnonymous]
 public IActionResult About()
    {
        ViewData["Message"] = "Your application description page.";

        return View();
    }
```

so is it possible to make some pages publically accessible in windows authentication?

Comment: Did you try with changing an authorization inside web.config file?

Comment: nope,
in .net core we don't have web.config file

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is possible. This is how I managed to do it in ASP.NET Core 2.0.x (not sure if it works in ASP.NET Core 1.x).

#### 1. Create a middleware that allows to discriminate between controllers that use Windows authentication and those which do not

```
/// <summary>
/// a middleware that allows that some requests to bypass Windows authentication
/// </summary>
public class NtlmAndAnonymousSetupMiddleware
{
    #region Variables
    private readonly RequestDelegate _next;

    //TODO: maybe this can be improved to get rid of these magic strings
    private List<string> AllowedControllers = new List<string>
    {
        "/Anonymous",
        "/swagger"
    };
    #endregion

    /// <summary>
    /// 
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="next"></param>
    public NtlmAndAnonymousSetupMiddleware(RequestDelegate next)
    {
        this._next = next;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// 
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="context"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public async Task Invoke(HttpContext context)
    {
        // if requests target anonymous controller or there is a CORS related OPTIONS request
        // => let it be and challenge only for other request methods (GET, POST etc.)
        if (context.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated ||
            context.Request.Method == "OPTIONS" ||
            AllowedControllers.Any(c =>
            {
                string path = context.Request.Path.ToString();
                return path.StartsWith(c, StringComparison.InvariantCulture);
            }))
        {
            await _next(context);
            return;
        }

        await context.ChallengeAsync("Windows");
    }

}
```

A special case is when receiving OPTIONS requests (CORS related) that must not reach the Windows authentication challenge.

#### 2. Register the middleware in Startup.cs

```
/// <summary>
/// allow anonymous requests (that are handled by application afterwards)
/// </summary>
/// <param name="app"></param>
protected virtual void AllowAnonymous(IApplicationBuilder app)
{
    app.UseMiddleware<NtlmAndAnonymousSetupMiddleware>();
}

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app)
{
    AllowAnonymous(app);
    // ...
}
```

#### 3. Allow anonymous authentication in IIS

Of course, the Web applicatio should be configured to also allow Anonymous authentication (besides Windows authentication)

**Note:** referring to web.config, I do not remember if this was required in ASP.NET Core 1.x, but I always use it when hosting in IIS:

```
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <handlers> 
      <add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="*" modules="AspNetCoreModule" resourceType="Unspecified" />
    </handlers>
    <aspNetCore processPath="dotnet" arguments=".\TheApp.dll" stdoutLogEnabled="false" stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout" forwardWindowsAuthToken="true" /> 
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```